# How can I attribute a midnight value (dd/mm/yyyy 00:00) to the previous day?

Tags: pandas

I have data which accumulate and log each half hour. Therefore, the data logged at midnight (e.g. 27/01/2019 00:00) is actually relevant to the previous day (26/01/2019). This causes problems when totalling daily values

I understand it might be possible to recode the 00:00 as 23:59 to make sure it sits within 26/01/2019, but is there a cleaner/more pythonic way to approach?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is that your logs record at midnight when they actually correspond to the half hour prior to midnight, why not just apply this to all of your records. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

# ...

df['Log Period Start'] = df['Log Time'] - pd.Timedelta(minute=30)
```

Then apply your calculations to `'Log Period Start'` rather than `'Log Time'`.

Comment: Why not pd.Timedelta(day=1)?

Comment: @MohitMotwani That way you would mess up all the other times. The answer is valid for the whole dataframe.

Comment: You're right. This is only relevant to the data logged at midnight. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Great idea - a good work around to document that 2330 is the data from 2330-0000, perhaps the most straight forward way.